# Read a file with a mix of names and numbers and put them into different arrays

Tags: java, arrays, readfile

I'm in a java introduction class and I know this question might be really simple to you, but I do need help. 
So I'm trying to read from a file in which contains names and income, and I would like to read them into different arrays.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class caltax
{
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    String lname[] = new String [12];
    String fname[] = new String [12];
    Double income[] = new Double [12];
    double sincome=0.0;
    int i, count=1;

try 
{
  Scanner infile = new Scanner (new FileInputStream("family.dat"));

  while (infile.hasNextLine())
  {

    lname[12] = infile.next();
    fname[12] = infile.next();
    income[12] = infile.nextDouble();

  }//while

  infile.close();

}//try
catch (Exception e)
{
  System.out.println("Check the file");
}//catch block    

for(i=0;i<12;i++)
{
if (lname[i].equals(lname[i+1]))
{
  count++;
  sincome += income[i];

  //object t is created and constrctor is called 
  taxcalculation t = new taxcalculation (count, lname, fname, sincome);
  t.taxowned();
}//if 

}//for  
 }//main
}//class
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You get index out of bounds error, right? You're putting all the values in the same position in the arrays.

Comment: the question is to read from the file and calculate tax that a family(as a whole) needs to pay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. I guess it is just typo lname[**12**], fname[**12**],income[**12**] in that while:

```
while (infile.hasNextLine())
{
 lname[12] = infile.next();
 fname[12] = infile.next();
 income[12] = infile.nextDouble();
```

}//while

Assuming that you need only first 12 lines from the file, it must look like:

```
int lineIdx =0;
while (infile.hasNextLine() && lineIdx < 12)
{
 lname[lineIdx] = infile.next();
 fname[lineIdx] = infile.next();
 income[lineIdx] = infile.nextDouble();
 lineIdx++;
}//while
```

---

Updated: working logic (please read through comments in code)... sorry for delay.

```
        // 1. Define two arrays
    String[] families = null;
    double[] taxes = null;

    // 2. Read file:
    while (infile.hasNextLine()) {
        String personLastName = infile.next();
        // skip first name
        infile.next();
        double personTax = infile.nextDouble();
        // add person data
        if (null == families) {
            // create array for
            families = new String[] { personLastName };
            taxes = new double[] { personTax };
        } else {
            boolean familyExists = false;
            // check existing families
            for (int i = 0; i < families.length; i++) {
                if (personLastName.equals(families[i])) {
                    // got it! add personTax to family owed taxes
                    taxes[i] += personTax;
                    familyExists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!familyExists) {
                // Extend arrays to put new family
                // create temp arrays with size+1
                String[] tmpFamilies = new String[families.length + 1];
                double[] tmpTaxes = new double[taxes.length + 1];
                System.arraycopy(families, 0, tmpFamilies, 0, families.length);
                System.arraycopy(taxes, 0, tmpTaxes, 0, taxes.length);
                // set new last elements data
                tmpFamilies[tmpFamilies.length - 1] = personLastName;
                tmpTaxes[tmpTaxes.length - 1] = personTax;
                // replace families and taxes with newly created tmp arrays
                families = tmpFamilies;
                taxes = tmpTaxes;
            }
        }
    }// while
    // Print results
    System.out.println("Found " + families.length + " families and their taxes");       
    for (int i=0;i < families.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("family " + families[i] + " owes $" + taxes[i]);
    }
```

Comment: still won't work. the file only have 12 lines, they look like " John Smith 23745.08" "Sally Smith 45670.00" then I need to group all the people from same family and calculate tax that this family needs to pay

Comment: That is different story and you did not ask for that initially. It needs different approach and solution with 3 arrays is quite clumsy and too far from good. In short you need to use a HashMap<String,Double> key is last name, value is total taxes. Then while you read a line from file take last name, if it is in HasMap already, add value, if it is not put a new Entry in the Map. That it. At the end you will have a Map with families and their taxes. BTW: How many records are in the file does not matter in that case.

Comment: ok, but my professor didn't mention anything about map in this class, so I assume she does not want us to do in that way. Is there any different ways to do this?

Comment: got it. How old is she  ? :) just kidding. In general it is from old ages of programming when there was nothing else but arrays. From other hands it makes much better sense from basics of programming. And yes there many many ways to do it. So, with arrays only look at what you need actually - list of families and corresponding to them sum of taxes. Of course Map serves it perfectly. But we do not have Map... OOP approach - we can have an object with Family and sum of taxes as properties of that object. Then Set, List or Array of such objects will be good.  OK, we are not on OOP...

Comment: what to do? We can emulate Map with two arrays. First holds Family last name, Second sum of taxes... Only one thing we have to aware is indexes they must match. i.e. taxes for family[1] must be in taxes[1] etc. Other restriction is for Java. Java does not have unknown size arrays and cannot extend existing ones. If we need to extend an array we have to create new one with size+1 copy there old one and assign new values to the last element. That means logic will be... please see my updated response comment is not a good place for it...

Comment: Sorry, had something else... Update is comming soon... :)

Comment: Logic is same as for map - if family already exists - add tax if not increase arrays and put new family data

Comment: Finally that code is completely out of OOP and its not even Procedural. it can be rewritten in very old languages like first version of Fortran (from last century 50-ies :)  have fun! :)

Comment: Wow, I just tried the updated version and it worked perfectly! Thanks a lot! I know assignments in class do not make sense sometimes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are always welcome. It is not only about assignments in class :) it happens all the time in real job too :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to read them into different arrays?  Is that what your assignment asks for?  A better solution to this is to create an object with your properties like Employee, then add each Employee to a `List<Employee>`

If you're asking how to iteratively add items to your array, you need an index that starts at 0 and ends at array.length - 1.

Comment: yeah, I need to print them separately. The output should tax amount that a family need to pay (so group family members together)

Comment: because I need to compare last names and then group people from the same family together to calculate the tax this family owe